# plotting a marker from the latitude and longitude coming from database

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Here what i have done.

```
function xmlParser(xml) {

    $('#load').fadeOut();

    $(xml).find("da").each(function () {

        $(".main").append('<div class="data"><div class="name">Name ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</div><div class="latitude">Latitude ' + $(this).find("lat").text() + '</div><div class="longitube">Longitude ' + $(this).find("lng").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".data").fadeIn(1000);
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();     
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text(); 
        $("#map").goMap({ 
           markers: [{  

                latitude: lat, 
                longitude: lng, 
                html: { 
                    id: '.data', 
                    popup: true 
                } 
            },{  
                latitude: 54.948813, 
                longitude: 21.704004, 
                html: { 
                    id: '.name' 
                } 
            }] 
        }); 

    });
```

The data is coming from xml file.
Only thing is i want to somehow plot the marker using the values coming in lat and lng variables.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Are you asking how to get multiple values instead of one value from an xml file? I'm guessing from just reading code that only one marker shows up, and you're trying to get multiple to show up?

Comment: only one for now..no marker doesnt show up.."latitude:lat,longitude:lng" I think this is not right.

Comment: Does the map load? Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution
Instead of

```
var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();     
var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
```

Write

```
var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());     
var lng = parseFloat($(this).find('lng').text());
```